# How to retrieve text from dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I must audit the changes into a database. On most pages this works perfect, as there were just textboxes - however on a page I am working on right now, with dropdownlists, my code isn't working.

```
<td>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDatacountry" DataTextField="country_name" DataValueField="country_id">
  </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDatacountry" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:songtypecons %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [country_detail]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</td>
```

code behind:

```
string sql1 = "selectcust_fname,cust_mname,cust_lname,cust_birthdate,cust_gender,cust_address,cust_contact_num,cust_country,cust_state,cust_city,cust_zip from cust_detail where cust_id ='" + ds.Tables["filldata"].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() + "' ";
            SqlDataAdapter adpt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, con);
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            adpt1.Fill(ds1, "custdata");
            if (ds1.Tables["custdata"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

             for (int d = 0; d < DropDownList4.Items.Count; d++)
            {
               if (ds1.Tables["custdata"].Rows[0].ItemArray[7].ToString() == DropDownList4.Items[d].Text)
              {
                   DropDownList4.Items[d].Selected = true;
                   break;
               }
           }
        }
```

Comment: Can't you just use DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text to retrieve the value of the selected item? There's no need to loop through all items.

Comment: You should always use [_parameterized queries_](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of codes are open for an [_SQL Injection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Just Write ur code in the event of dropdownlist named Dropdownlist4_selectedIndexChanged

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question clearly, you just need to use your code in your [`ListControl.SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event.

> Occurs when the selection from the list control changes between posts
>   to the server.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged" ...>
</asp:DropDownList>

protected void DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

As I wrote in my *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009181/how-to-retrieve-text-from-dropdownlist/16009377#comment22831645_16009181)*, you should always use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)* in your sql commands, your code is open for an *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.